# Verilog 8 bit comparator from 2 bit comparators Where do I start?

Tags: verilog

Hello I am new to the programming world. I have a project for my ece 171 class that I have been trying to figure out on my own but cannot. I had a project before where I needed to design a 2 bit comparator which I did design successfully. Now I am supposed to take that 2 bit comparator and alter it as well as write some more verilog code that will compare 8 bits with each other using my expanded 2 bit program. My problem is that I don't know where to even start. My professor said always start with a black box and then truth table. My initial instinct is to create a 16 bit truth table which I know is wrong. But I don't even know where to start? Any suggestions? I feel like if I could just be shown where the path starts that it would start coming to me.
My 2-bit comparator code below.

```
//two 2-bit input Values Comparer Behavioral Dataflow

//Defining Module and Parameters

module BcompareA(A, B, GT, EQU, LT);

input [1:0] A;
input [1:0] B;

output GT;//when a is greater than b
output EQU;//when a is equal to b
output LT;//when a is less than b

//Boolean Output Descriptions

assign  GT =    A[1]&~B[1] 
          | A[1]&A[0]&~B[0] 
          | A[0]&~B[1]&~B[0]


assign  EQU =    ~A[1]&~A[0]&~B[1]&~B[0] 
           | ~A[1]&A[0]&~B[1]&B[0] 
           | A[1]&A[0]&B[1]&B[0] 
           | A[1]&~A[0]&B[1]&~B[0]


assign  LT =    ~A[1]&B[1] 
          | ~A[1]&~A[0]&B[0] 
          | ~A[0]&B[1]&B[0]


endmodule
```

Comment: Why don't you simply define 4 2-bit comparators that compares bits `[7:6], [5:4], [3:2], [1:0]` and use some logic for `GT`, `EQU` and `LT` signals?

Answer (score 0):

You should use yours 2 bit comparator to compare pairs of bits [7:6], [5,4],...
Lets start with EQU output - it is the easiest. A and B would be equal if all its pairs would be equal. So logic is simple.
Make a notice that A would be greater if its highest bits are greater (GT_76 == 1 ) or highest bits are equal( EQU_76 == 1 ) and next pair would be greater ( GT_54 = 1 ) or etc.
Finally A would be less if it is not greater and not equal.